# Como adicionar um valor ao DBF

Tags: delphi, microsoft-excel, delphi-xe8

Para fazer a leitura do arquivo .DBF trabalho da seguinte maneira:

Uso um TADOConnection, sendo a **ConnectionString** para:

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=C:\_workspace\projects\DBFEditor\temp
```

Para ler o arquivo DBF uso um **TADOQuery** definindo a propriedade SQL para a consulta:

```
Select * from <arquivodbf>
```

Sendo assim tenho essas colunas no meu arquivo dbf.

```
INDICE  NOME    COR ESTILO  ESCALA
100     SAOJOAO      18      0,00
```

Eu preciso trocar o nome da coluna **INDICE** PARA **ID**, para isso estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
  while not ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      Adoquery1.Edit;
      ADOQuery1.FieldByName('NOME').TEXT:= 'ID';
      Adoquery1.Post;
      ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
```

porem eu recebo o seguinte resultado, ao abrir meu excel:

```
INDICE  NOME    COR ESTILO  ESCALA
 ID     SAOJOAO      18      0,00
```

como eu espero o resultado:

```
 ID        NOME    COR ESTILO  ESCALA
 100     SAOJOAO        18      0,00
```

Comment: Você não altera o nome da coluna, só altera dados nelas. Até deve ter alguma forma, mas em Delphi eu não sei fazer, só externamente.

Comment: Mas tecnicamente eu eu estou setando um valor, o campo INDICE, não deixa de ser um campo

Comment: O que eu entendi é que deseja mudar o nome dele, essa é uma operação complexa que o ADo não deve ser capaz de fazer, pelo menos não de forma tradicional. Mudar dado é uma coisa, mudar o nome da coluna é outra. E esse código está bem confuso, pra falar a verdade que está postado aí nem acontece de verdade.

Comment: Exatamente isso que preciso, vou mudar para um jeito mais simples, mas está funcionando sim.

Comment: Você indica alguma maneira que possa estar fazendo isso?

Comment: Só para eu entender melhor, tens um .dbf e para se conectar a esse banco de dados tais usando o componente TADO, percorrendo os registros com o ADOQuery e salvando as informações no Excel?... se eu estiver errado me corrija.

Comment: Exato, a questão que o @bigown disse que não é possível mudar o "header" que seria a primeira linha do  arquivo usando o DAO

Comment: Nesse caso, a melhor forma é montar um comando `alter`, e executar diretamente com o Delphi. Para isso basta utilizar o `ExecuteDirect()` do `SQLConnection`.

Comment: Só para complementar esse comando que você utiliza `ADOQuery1.FieldByName('NOME').TEXT:= 'ID';` está explicito que você está alterando o conteúdo do Field 'NOME' quando você utiliza o .Text que é uma propriedade do objeto.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf, pelo que entendi, ele quer mudar o nome do Field, e não o conteúdo. A não ser que eu esteja enganado.

Comment: Exatamente, quero mudar o nome do FIELD

Comment: Para poder mudar os Fields, tens que percorrer eles, faça o seguinte... antes de percorrer as informações tens que alterar os fields e então alimentar com os dados. Tente fazer um for no ADOQuery.FieldsDefs.Cout-1 e pegando o primeiro Field, fazendo assim... ADOQuery1.FieldsDefs[0].Name := 'ID'

Comment: @VictorZanella, ele tem que percorrer os fields da query para poder alterar

Comment: Eu acho que seria mais fácil você montar um comando externo, como o @bigown cogitou, e esse comando você executa pelo seu SQLConnection. Ex `MySQLConnection.ExecuteDirect('ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype')`

Comment: @VictorZanella vc consegueria formular uma resposta com o que comentou? ajudaria bastante

Comment: Não formulei uma resposta, porque não tenho certeza. O que acontece é que em momento algum você afirmou que estava utilizando alguma base de dados. Deduzi isso pela extensão do arquivo. Dai eu não sei se você realmente usa um SQLConnection. Se você confirmar isso para min, Editar a sua pergunta colocando mais código, eu poderia formular uma resposta.

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta, caso ainda não estiver claro pode mandar aqui ou me chamar por chat

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, seria interessante você passar o conteúdo da ADOQuery para uma tabela temporária do Delphi, um componente muito bom para manipular esses dados seria o TClientDataSet, você cria os Fields que você quer e percorre a sua ADOQuery alimentando o ClientDataSet, depois que tiver atualizado o ClientDataSet, é só percorrer ele e montar o dados para serem visualizados no Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um exemplo de como poderia fazer, segue abaixo:

> Declare no uses Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient

```
var
  oCDSDados: TClientDataSet;
  iPos: Integer;
begin
  oCDSDados := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
try
  oCDSDados.FieldDefs.Add('ID',ftInteger);
  oCDSDados.FieldDefs.Add('NOME',ftString,50);
  oCDSDados.FieldDefs.Add('COR_ESTILO',ftInteger);
  oCDSDados.FieldDefs.Add('ESCALA',ftFloat);
  oCDSDados.CreateDataSet;

  ADOQuery1.First;
  while not (ADOQuery1.Eof) do
  begin
    oCDSDados.Append;
    oCDSDados.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger         := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('INDICE').AsInteger;
    oCDSDados.FieldByName('NOME').AsString        := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('NOME').AsString;
    oCDSDados.FieldByName('COR_ESTILO').AsInteger := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('COR_ESTILO').AsInteger;
    oCDSDados.FieldByName('ESCALA').AsFloat       := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('ESCALA').AsFloat;
    oCDSDados.Post;
    ADOQuery1.Next;
  end;

  //Primeira linha para incluir os fields no Excel.
  for iPos := 0 to oCDSDados.FieldDefs.Count-1 do
  begin
    // para pegar os fields do ClientDataSet
    oCDSDados.FieldDefs[iPos].Name;
  end;

  oCDSDados.First;
  while not (oCDSDados.Eof) do
  begin
    //
    // ESTRUTA PARA MONTAR O DADOS NO EXCEL
    //

   oCDSDados.Next;
 end;
finally
  if (oCDSDados.Active) then
    oCDSDados.Close;
  FreeAndNil(oCDSDados);
end;
end;
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!

Comment: FieldsDefs.Count-1 tire que alterar Para FieldDefs.Count-1 por que ele nao reconhecia Fields e ele retornou: E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'string' found

Comment: Desculpe, é FieldDefs.Cout-1 vou arrumar, tens como colocar uma parte do código a onde ele da o problema

Comment: é na função  oCDSDados.FieldDefs[iPos].Name; E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'string' found.. eu coloquei em vez de name, DisplayName..ai ele roda, mas não sei se é o jeito certo

Comment: Você criou o arquivo do Excel antes do for e dentro do for tens que jogar os fields do clientdataset na primeira linha do Excel, qual o Delphi que tais usando?

Comment: estou usando delphi-xe8

Comment: era para funcionar, como que tais alimentando a variável com o retorno do oCDSDados.FieldDefs[iPos].Name? mas depois que você colocou o DisplayName funcionou tudo?... ou deu mais algum problema

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47128/discussion-between-guilherme-lima-and-jefferson-rudolf).

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, conseguiu resolver o problema?